# Placing text characters w/ javascript without using a div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am going to be placing a lot of characters and words all over a web page using absolute positioning. I could put each character in it's own div, then set it's position. Is there any other way to place an individual word or character on a page without putting it in a div (to save memory). I figure not (which is fine), but if there is another way I'd like to explore it.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You will need to put your text into an object that can be positioned, so you will need a div or span.

Comment: You might want to look at Dave Rupert's [Lettering.JS](http://letteringjs.com), which will basically put all the letters in your text into separate elements, with controllable classes etc.

Comment: Why do you think divs are memory-consuming? I've seen performance tests manipulate over ten thousands divs, and it were fine.

Comment: @Andre Good point. I just assumed that having a div wrapper would add an inefficiency of some sort, but I guess that wouldn't necessarily be the case.

Comment: @Pointy Wow! That's pretty amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using html canvas. It will allow you to draw text to it at any position you want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas

Comment: This looks promising! The power!! I'm going to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tags like `<b>` and set their `css` to `font-weight: normal;`.

If you are going to be worry about the DOM tree size, you can go ahead with this way of implementation. But what is the use of implementing this? There are plenty of jQuery and JavaScript snippets available right?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some type of html tag surrounding the text or else you will have no way to apply CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in the manner you are imagining. Anonymous boxes cannot be manipulated and, generally speaking, do not carry traditional properties. You will have to use a wrapper tag.

you can read more here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level